# Is there any specific symbol for the signum function like $\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $\lceil x \rceil$ for the floor and ceiling functions respectively?

Tags: functions

Let's say that a function $f$ gives the greatest integer smaller than or equal to $x$.

So, $f(x)$ can be replaced by $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Similarly, is there some similar symbol for the signum function too? The signum function is defined as :
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 1,& x > 0 \\ -1,& x < 0\\ 0,& x = 0 \end{cases} = \begin{cases}\dfrac{|x|}{x},& x \neq 0 \\ 0,& x = 0 \end{cases}$$
where $g$ is the signum function.

Thanks!

Comment: I usually just see $\text{Sign}(x)$

Comment: Yeah, Desmos uses that too. Using symbols like $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is more fun though :P. Thanks!

Comment: $\operatorname{Sgn}(x)$ is commonly used.

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks!